# Does Android OpenGL ES use Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am building an Android app that uses OpenGL ES 2.0

In My `GLSurfaceView`, I log `this.isHardwareAccelerated()` and it is false.

Does this mean OpenGL is not using the GPU on the device?

Note: Im using an imx6 processor which has the Vivante GPU

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is instructions specifically for the GPU. They cannot be run on the CPU. Android's  hardware acceleration features apply to 2D graphics in `android.graphics.canvas` and `android.graphics.view`. Hardware Acceleration is enabled by default for 2D views, and this routes the graphics pipeline through... You guessed it: OpenGL.

The fact that `GLSurfaceView` has a method called `.IsHardwareAccelerated()` is only because it inherits it from `View`. `GLSurfaceView` bypasses the `View` pipeline, however, and handles commands to the EGL that you give it. In other words, it's more of a helper class to OpenGL, and less of an actual view component.